# ELK LDAP log filtering

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, kibana, elastic-stack

Two things: Our logs look like this -

`May 11 06:51:31 ldap slapd[6694]: conn=1574001 op=1 SRCH base="cn=s_02,ou=users,o=meta" scope=0 deref=0 filter="(...)"` 
I need to 1) take the time stamp and set it to the left column "time" in Kibana's discover panel and 2) take the number after connection and make it a field so as to be able to order them by number. I've spent all day researching and date and mutate seem promising, but I haven't been able to get them correctly implemented. 
The config file looks like this:

```
input {
   file {
      path => "/Desktop/logs/*.log"
      type => "log"
      sincedb_path => "/dev/null"
   }
}

output {

  elasticsearch {
    hosts => "127.0.0.1"
    index => "logstash-%{type}-%{+YYYY.MM.dd}"
  }

  file {
    path => "/home/logsOut/%{type}.%{+yyyy.MM.dd.HH.mm}"
  }
}
```

Comment: Do you want only that two fields?

Answer (score 0):

If you only need these two as seperate fields:

```
filter {
    grok {
        match => { 
            "message" => [ "%{SYSLOGBASE} conn=%{INT:conn}" ]
        }
    }

    date {
        match => [ "timestamp", "MMM dd HH:mm:ss" ]
        target => "time"
    }

    mutate {
        convert => { "conn" => "integer" }
    }
}
```

Comment: So the timestamp generates a new field within the results - is there a way to move it over to the time column? I think that's what you're trying to do but it's not taking for me. Also, I need to order the logs by conn and I see what you're doing but I'm confused on how to work with it.

Comment: I think I could just use the visualization tools for this. Trying to learn it now. Thanks!